# sql query to select columns by condition on specific column(with out aggregate function) with group by

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a sql query with group by so that i can get columns from the same raw by condition on one column, I can not use aggregate function

e.g Employee table

```
EmpId   data1 data2 data3 reg_date
--------------------------------------
1       1     2     2     2013/06/12
1       5     6     7     2013/06/13
```

I want group by EmpId And want All other data where reg_date is maximum.

```
SELECT EmpId,data1,data2,data3,reg_date FROM Employee
GROUP BY EmpId
```

Obviously this will give error because it needs aggregate function for data1,data2,data3 and reg_date to decide which value out of two to select.

But can I use MAX function for reg_date and all data field can be selected for that max date

Comment: Ya u can try using MAX. it will be good if u post your code so that we will able to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it by using `Row_Number` and `Partiton` ..this assume to be best in case like this...you can try like this...

```
Select EmpId,data1,data2,data3,reg_date from 
( 
SELECT Row_Number()  Over(Partition By EmpId Order by reg_date desc) as Row, EmpId,data1,data2,data3,reg_date FROM Employee
) t where t.Row=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query below should roughly do what you need. So in the first select it gets the empID in combination with the latest reg_date. THe second select gets all the data in the table and in the final select we join the 2 datasets on the criteria listed which should get you the empID, the max regdate and the values for data1, data2, data3 that correspond.

```
;with
  GetDataSet1 as
  (
  SELECT EmpId,MAX(reg_date) "MaxRegDate" 
  FROM Employee 
  GROUP BY EmpId
  )
  ,GetDataSet2 as
  (
   SELECT EmpId,data1,data2,data3,reg_date
   FROM Employee 
  )
  select *
  FROM GetDataSet1 a
  JOIN GetDataSet2 b on a.EmpID = b.EmpID AND a.MaxRegDate = b.reg_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.EmpId,t1.Data1,t1.Data2,t1.Data3, MAX(Reg_date) AS MAXDATES FROM
(SELECT EmpId,Data1,Data2,Data3, MAX(Reg_date) AS MAXDATE
FROM Employee
GROUP BY EmpId,Data1,Data2,Data3 ) as t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT EmpId, MAX(Reg_date) AS MAXDATE
SELECT EmpId,Data1,Data2,Data3
FROM Employee) as t2
ON t1.EmpId=t2.EmpId
GROUP BY t1.EmpId,t1.Data1,t1.Data2,t1.Data3
```

Try this and see.

Comment: You can't do a max(reg_date) like so as it would only group them if the values for data1, data2 and data3 are the same for each record, otherwise you generate duplicate entries.